# sortable check boxes with a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, checkbox

hi bit of a noob to this, but is it possible to have 3 check boxes and hide my a tag when one is checked but the if checkbox 2 is checked it hides that as well then when you uncheck checkbox 1 it will still stay hidden if the other checkbox is checked, like a sortable option

```
<input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check1"><label>check1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check2"><label>check2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check3"><label>check3</label>

<a class="check1 check2" href="">check1</a>
<a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
<a class="check3" href="">check3</a>

<a class="check1" href="">check1</a>
<a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
<a class="check3 check2" href="">check3</a>

<a class="check1 check2" href="">check1</a>
<a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
<a class="check3" href="">check3</a>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$(function () { 
    $('.example').change(function() {
       theID = this.id;
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
        $("." + theID).addClass("hide"); 
} else {
 $("." + theID).removeClass("hide");
}
});
 // Check while loading.
 $(".example").each(function () { 
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
   $("." + this.id).removeClass("hide"); 
});

});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? It certainly sounds possible, but it's not clear the logic you want to follow.

Comment: Hi Dave, erm here goes...

Comment: if i check checkbox 1 and checkbox 2 it adds a hide clsss to the a tag with the same class. but if i uncheck checkbox 1 but leave checkbox 2 checked  everything whith check2 stays hidden but everything with check1 is now visable

Comment: is that any better..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a checkbox changes state, do the following:

1. Get all the IDs of the checked boxes
2. Take these IDs and [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) them into a [comma-delimited](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) jQuery class selector
3. Hide all `a` tags, then show the ones that match any of your stored classes

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').hide();
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  var checkedClasses = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').toArray().map(function(e) {
    return '.' + e.id;
  });
  var selector = checkedClasses.join(',');
  $('a').hide().filter(selector).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check1"><label for="check1">check1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check2"><label for="check2">check2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check3"><label for="check3">check3</label>

<a class="check1 check2" href="">check1</a>
<a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
<a class="check3" href="">check3</a>

<a class="check1" href="">check1</a>
<a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
<a class="check3 check2" href="">check3</a>

<a class="check1 check2" href="">check1</a>
<a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
<a class="check3" href="">check3</a>
```

Comment: yes thats close, when you check all three and then uncheck check1 this a tag should still be showing <a class="check1 check2" href="">check1</a> is that correct as it has 2 classes

Comment: It does have two classes, but I am not sure why it should show. The way it is written, when you uncheck `check1` it hides anything with `class="check1"`. What am I missing?

Comment: yes thats correct how ever if check 2 is checked i need that to still show?

Comment: I think I got it now. Take a look at the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below. is this what you require. Hide on respective checkbox no.

```js
$(function () { 
    $('.example').change(function() {
          $("[class*=check]").removeClass("hide"); 
          $(".example:checked").each(function () { 
                $("." + this.id).addClass("hide"); 
          });
     });
});
```

```css
.hide{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check1"><label>check1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check2"><label>check2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check3"><label>check3</label>
<br/>

<a class="check1 check2" href="">check1</a>
<a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
<a class="check3" href="">check3</a>
<br/>
<a class="check1" href="">check1</a>
<a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
<a class="check3 check2" href="">check3</a>
<br/>
<a class="check1 check2" href="">check1</a>
<a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
<a class="check3" href="">check3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/7mn2r9tb/

On checkbox click show all a's, and then get the checked boxes and hide all a's that contain the checked element's id in its class.

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() { 
    $("a").removeClass("hide"); 

    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){ 
       var theID = this.id;
       $("a[class*=" + theID + "]").addClass("hide");
    });
});
```